# DIV inline-block + width 100%

Tags: css, css-tables

I can't display a few DIV's in one line. `display: inline-block` and `float: left` doesn't work. My site width is not `fixed` so I want it to be dynamic to fit any width of screen.

---

**HTML:**

```
<div id="all">
    <div id="a">25px</div>
    <div id="b">200px</div>
    <div id="c">
        <div id="c1">100%</div>
        <div id="c2">100%</div>
        <div id="c3">100%</div>
    </div>
    500px
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
DIV {
    margin:5px;
    font-size:10px;
}

DIV#all {
    width:500px;
    border:1px dotted black;
}

DIV#a {
    display:inline-block;
    width:25px;
    height:200px;
    border:1px solid red;
    color:red;
}

DIV#b {
    display:inline-block;
    width:150px;    
    height:200px;
    border:1px solid green;
    color:green;
}

DIV#c {
    display:inline-block;
    width:auto;
    height:200px;
    border:1px solid blue;
    color:blue;
}

DIV#c1 {
    width:auto;
    border:1px dotted blue;
    color:blue;   
}

DIV#c2 {
    width:auto;
    border:1px dotted blue;    
}

DIV#c3 {
    width:auto;
    border:1px dotted blue;   
    color:blue;
}​
```

**Live Demos:**

- **PROBLEM:** http://jsfiddle.net/BC2d9/
- **RESOLVED:** http://jsfiddle.net/RAds3/ (`display:table`)

​

Comment: You want float:left not display:inline-block

Comment: There is some inconsistent behaviour in your solution. If you look closer, the middle div B1 should be 200px wide, but it's not. It has width only 150px. Any idea, why's that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem with your current attempt is the `width: 100%;` on the third column `div#c`. 100% here will be 100% of its parent - which contains all three columns. Depending on what level of flexibility you want you have a few options.

If the site width is fixed, set a fixed width for the third column.

If you want the third column to stretch to its content, set max-width.

If you want the third column to stretch to fill its parent, you're probably better off with (css) tables.

Check out http://somacss.com/cols.html for a great resource on css column layout.

Comment: Thanks! and display:table is best solution for me.

Comment: @clavish `display:table` isn't supported in IE 6

Answer (score 3):

Problem is with third column. You can't set width to 100%. Also, you need `float: left;`. Here is fixed code:

```
<div id="all">
    <div id="a">25px</div>
    <div id="b">200px</div>
    <div id="c">
        <div id="c1">100%</div>
        <div id="c2">100%</div>
        <div id="c3">100%</div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    500px
</div>
```

and CSS:

```css
DIV {
    margin:5px;
    font-size:10px;
}

DIV#all {
    width:500px;
    border:1px dotted black;
}

DIV#a {
    float: left;
    width:25px;
    height:200px;
    border:1px solid red;
    color:red;
}

DIV#b {
    float: left;
    width:200px;    
    height:200px;
    border:1px solid green;
    color:green;
}

DIV#c {
    float: left;
    width:210px; 
    min-height:190px;
    border:1px solid blue;
    color:blue;
    padding: 5px;
}

DIV#c1 {
    width:100%;
    border:1px dotted blue;
    color:blue;
    margin: 0 0 5px 0;   
}

DIV#c2 {
    width:100%;
    border:1px dotted blue;
    margin: 0 0 5px 0;   
}

DIV#c3 {
    width:100%;
    border:1px dotted blue;   
    color:blue;
    margin: 0 0 5px 0;
}​
```

And also [**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/BC2d9/5/)

Answer (score 1):

If your site width is fixed, then just replace `100%` with all remained width in the container.
**Example: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BC2d9/8/)**

---

If you want it to be dynamic and to fit any width of screen, I think it's not possible with pure CSS. I made it with jQuery:

```
var containerWidth = $('#all').outerWidth();
var widthLeft = $('#a').outerWidth(true) + $('#b').outerWidth(true);
var widthRight = containerWidth - widthLeft - 20; // 20px = spacing between elements

$('#c').css('width', widthRight+ 'px');
$('#c1, #c2, #c3').css('width', widthRight-10+ 'px'); // 10 = padding on the right side
```

Modified CSS:

```css
DIV#c {
    display:inline-block;
    height:200px;
    border:1px solid blue;
    color:blue;
    float: right;
}

DIV#c1 {
    border:1px dotted blue;
    color:blue;   
}

DIV#c2 {
    border:1px dotted blue;    
}

DIV#c3 {
    border:1px dotted blue;   
    color:blue;
}
```

Removed `width: 100%` and set `float:right` to `#c`.

**Live demo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BC2d9/7/)**

Comment: This is the quickest solutions for jQuery users. If you want to resolve this in pure css try @xec solution.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this update](http://jsfiddle.net/BC2d9/6/). I hope is good enough :)

```css
DIV {
margin:5px;
font-size:10px;
}

DIV#all {
    width:500px;
    border:1px dotted black;
}

DIV#a {
    display:inline-block;
    width:25px;
    height:200px;
    border:1px solid red;
    color:red;
    float:left;
}

DIV#b {
    display:inline-block;
    width:150px;    
    height:200px;
    border:1px solid green;
    color:green;
    float:left;
}

DIV#c {
    display:inline-block;
    width:277px; 
    height:200px;
    border:1px solid blue;
    padding:0 7px 0 5px;
    color:blue;
    float:left;
}

DIV#c1 {
    width:100%;
    margin:5px 0;
    border:1px dotted blue;
    color:blue; 
}

DIV#c2 {
    width:100%;
    margin:5px 0;
    border:1px dotted blue;    
}

DIV#c3 {
    width:100%;
    margin:5px 0;
    border:1px dotted blue;   
    color:blue;
}
```

Comment: "this update" is a link to jsfiddle where you can see the changes

Comment: I know, but it's essential to include some code and point to your changes. Also, jsFiddle links could be broken after some time.

Comment: You're right, I've already added the css part which has been modified

Answer (score -4):

```css
div { float:left; width:10px; height:10px; }
```

Helps?

Comment: I doubt it to be honest.